# Neo4j data modelling for often updates

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, data-modeling, graph-databases

Currently I have 50 000 Book nodes (`(Book {views:1, likes:1})`) each Book has properties `likes` and `views`. I am updating those counters every 10 minutes, but each update I am creating new node (`(:Update {time:timestamp(), views: 1, likes: 1)`) and linking it with the Book (`(:Update)-[:UPDATED]->(:Book)` . I want to do that because I want to show a visual presentation how views and likes change during time.

I am storing views and likes as properties because this data comes from 3rd party source and I can't do `(:User)-[:READ]->(:Book)`.

I am struggling to come up with a better solution for handling views and likes updates. Updates happen every 10 minutes and my graph grows very quickly. Queries like 'get last month's updates'  become very slow because Neo4j doesn't use indexes if the Cypher query where clause was used with range operators > or <.

**Example query 1**. It takes 2sec to complete because it does over a million DB hits.

```
MATCH (u:Update)-[r:UPDATED]->(b:BOOK)
WITH b, count(r) as totalUpdates 
RETURN b.id, totalUpdates
    ORDER BY totalUpdates
    DESC LIMIT 5
```

**Example query 2**. Takes ages, not usable at all

```
MATCH (u:Update)-[r:UPDATED]->(b:Book)
WHERE u.time<1448928000000 AND u.time>1446336000000
RETURN b, collect(u) AS updates
```

I was looking for data modelling solutions to solve this mess and I was not able to find any. Now I am confused about whether Neo4j is a bad choice for this, or may I need more CPU power to handle it, or there is a much better way to structure a graph like this.

Any suggestions or links to useful info are very welcome! Thank you.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? Range queries now make use of an index beginning with version 2.3. Verify you have an index on `Update.time` with the `:schema` command.

Comment: Thanks for reply, much appreciated. Added index on Update.time works faster. Just tested this query

MATCH (b:Book)<-[:UPDATED]-(u:Update) 
WHERE u.time >1444604400000
WITH v, su
ORDER BY u.viewCount DESC
WITH v, collect(b)[0] as todaysUpdate
RETURN b, b.viewCount - todaysUpdate.viewCount as todays
ORDER BY todays DESC
LIMIT 5

To get top 5 most growing(trending) books. Took 17s. Still very long time, any way I could improve structure or should I generate most growing books list and cache it? 

Thanks!

Comment: If the time range query is your primary kind of query you could graph the time dimension rather than the item dimension. Have you considered making a time tree and query for updates by their location in that tree rather than by an update label? In your query, the time dimension is a filter (or at best an index lookup) but if this is your primary kind of query it looks like it should be your domain structure.

Comment: If you query along both item and time dimensions it is also fine to record both. You can store multiple perspectives on your data in the same graph, to serve different kinds of queries.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks @jjaderberg . Will try to install https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree , migrate all data by using it and compare performance for time range queries. Looks very promising